# Java regular expression with hyphen is not count in length

Tags: java, regex

How do I can make regular expression, that accept all alphanumeric, except ,(coma).I tried the following expression [^,]{0,10}.but the hyphen is not counting in length.. Pls suggest me. My input is "12345-7890" and "1a2s2-6s7a"

Comment: If hyphen is allowed, then what other non alpha characters are also allowed?

Comment: Thank you Tim. All other characters are allowed and considering in length calculation, but hyphen is not consider in length calculation..

Comment: All other characters and alphanumeric is not the same thing.  Which one is it?

Comment: Tim,My requirement is allow all  alpha numeric except (, )coma. But length should not exceed 10.

Comment: If you don't want to include "," then simply use [^,]

Comment: When I pass hyphen in value.. Expression is not considering into length calculation...

Comment: Yes Adya..I did the same.. But I am facing problem with hyphen...

Comment: If you don't want to include "," and length should be 10 then use a quantifier as well [^,]{10}

Comment: You dont want to include "-" to be counted or dont want it in your expression? DO you really want hyphen in your expression ?

Comment: @Adya...if I pass the value is "12345-67890", the expression should return false.. But it's giving true ..this  is incorrect ..

Comment: I want to allow hyphen and should be counted...

Comment: If you are including hyphen then it will be true. Well on what condition are you checking its value as true/ false?

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question. Don't make others search for any relevant details in comment (not many people will do that, which means you are limiting amount of people which will be willing to help you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will exclude any pattern that contains a comma.

```
^((?!\-)[^\,]{0,10}|(?=\-)[^\,]{0,9})$
```

The regex will detect any hyphen and set the maximum length to 9 (if not contains hyphen) or 10 otherwise. So the hyphen still counts to length, which is adjusted dynamically. This only works with one hyphen.